# amazon-linux-extras specific version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-linux

[image]

I am trying to install a specific version using amazon-linux-extras but I have no idea how to do it. The usual way of doing it with yum seems to not work. Is there any way to do it?

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y tomcat8.5
```

The command above installs the latest.

Comment: can you explain more what doesn't work?  what errors are you seeing or what unexpected behavior is happening?

Comment: @JDD I have no idea how  to specify a version from that list

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your question properly!

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs, the format is `topic=version` if you want to install a specific version so try something like:

```
$ sudo amazon-linux-extras install tomcat8.5=8.5.31
```

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#extras-library